# Is there a multiple character version of strchr() in the standard C libraries?

Tags: c, parsing, string

In c if I wanted to search a string for a particular character I can just do the following

```
char *p;
p = (char *)strchr(buffer,'(');
if(p){
    ....
```

but what if I want to search for more than one character (or a character range) for example "any digit". I know I could do something like

```
char *p=0;
char *i;
for(i=buffer;*i!='\0';i++){
    if(*i >= '0' && *i <=9){
        p=i;
    }
}

if(p){
    ...
```

assuming a properly terminated string etc. But is there a standard library function that already provides this functionality (hopefully more safely)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What about [strpbrk](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strpbrk/)? Sounds like it fits your bill.

```
const char * strpbrk ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

"Returns a pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of any of the characters that are part of str2, or a null pointer if there are no matches."

EDIT: Link is to a C++ site, but `strpbrk` is part of the standard C library.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's just what I need.

Comment: +1- excellent answer. Perfectly suits the bill and within the constraints of the OP.